# whats the best way to approach multiple optional forms

Tags: usability, design

so I am designing a form that has multiple optional forms, where users will very rare use all of the options. I have so far thought about two different ways I could go about this.

The first would be to just show every optional form and let the user decide what to fill out and what they want to leave blank

[image: Option 1]

You can see that under the source, only the zone is required but the rest of the settings are optional. This lets the user see all their options, but I believe it provides a lot of unnecessary noise as most of the time, many users will only require 1 or two of these options.

The second option would let the user select which optional form they want to use and manually add more if they want.
[image: Option 2]

I am leaning towards option 2 since it reduces noise and still shows all the source options. I am just worried that the placement of the "add new row" button would confuse users into thinking they can only add additional IP addresses (or whatever their initial selection was) rather than adding a whole new category. (ex. MAC address)

I also tried adding the "add new row" button next to the source options, but feel that users may not notice it after adding their source information.

[image: Option 2 v2]

Any suggestions on how to approach this?